# Writing numpy.bool array to compact file?

Tags: python, numpy, bitarray

I'm using numpy and Python 2.7 to compute large (100 million+ elements) boolean arrays for a super-massive prime sieve and write them to binary files to read at a much later time.  NumPy bools are 8-bit, so the file size that I'm writing is much larger than necessary.  Since I'm writing a large number of these files I'd like to keep them as small as humanly possible without having to waste a lot of time/memory converting them to a bitarray and back.

I was originally going to switch to using the bitarray module to keep file size down, but the sieve computation time increased by around 400% with the same algorithms, which is a bit unacceptable.  Is there a fast-ish way to write and read back the ndarray in a smaller file, or is this a trade-off that I'm just going to have to deal with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`numpy.packbits`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) to turn it into a `uint8` array for writing, then [`numpy.unpackbits`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html#numpy.unpackbits) after reading it back. `numpy.packbits` pads the axis you're packing along with zeros to get to a multiple of 8, so make sure you keep track of how many zeros you'll need to chop off the end when you unpack the array.

Comment: Unless the size of the array is guaranteed to be a multiple of 8, he'll need to save to disk its length (or its length modulo 8), to chop off the last few zeros that `np.packbits` is going to add when packing it.

Comment: @Jaime: Very good point. I didn't even realize that would be an issue.